# Can you say "came to discussion"

Tags: american-english

I want to ask someone if a certain issue has ever been "brought up to discussion" or "came to discussion". Is it correct English?

Comment: If you are asking whether an issue has ever been addressed (as in a meeting) you would most likely say "brought up *for* discussion."  You could also use "brought up *in a* discussion* if you're asking specifically whether the idea has ever been mentioned, even peripherally, in a discussion.

Comment: @JasonPatterson can you post this as an answer so that the question is marked as answered, please? It is the correct answer, but posted in comment form for some reason.

Comment: @AlexK I posted it as a comment because it is an overly short and insufficient answer, in my opinion.  It's worthwhile to give a brief answer as a comment in case the person asking the question has time constraints.  If you would like to expand upon it and offer it as your own answer, you are more than welcome to do so.  :)

Comment: @JasonPatterson alright! Just wanted to make sure that it'd be okay to do that first. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Topics are brought up "in discussion".
Topics currently being talked about right now are "under discussion".

So you would say, "Has this issue ever been brought up in discussion." You can also use "Came" in a slightly different meaning. While "Brought up" implies that the issue was deliberately made the focus of the discussion, "came up in discussion" suggests that the issue has been discussed simply because the subject of the conversation naturally resulted in it being talked about.